# Android progressdialog don't show after onResume

Tags: android, multithreading, progressdialog

I have main activity with fragment with map on it. In action from menu in activity I create *ProgressDialog* with context of current activity, create new *Thread* with this *ProgressDialog* object in constructor and start it. Everything works fine, progress bar is controlled with message handler in thread.

Operations are long several minutes.

**Problem** occurred when I application is going to **background**. After resume in *onResume* I call show on existing instance of dialog but I don't see progress dialog.

When I call method onShowing() on that dialog, return is true, but dialog is not showing on activity. (is it possible that it is show 'behind' activity ? )

Do you know, what is wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Please upload the code with error ( if any ).

Comment: "Operations are long several minutes" unless this is absolutely necessary, I would suggest trying a different approach such as using a `Service`. Who wants to look at a `ProgressBar` for several minutes? Unless this was suppose to be tagged "MS"

Comment: @Kedarnath: there is no error, only probelm is that after application resume than progressdialog is not visible.

Comment: @codeMagic: Yes, I agree. But time for operation is variable from seconds to minutes. It is depenends of some circumstances... Mostly it takes a seconds, but I need cover that long one too.